# Using Docker to run a MongoDB Shell, Waiting for Connection After a While

Tags: mongodb, docker, terminal, docker-compose

I keep waiting for this to complete a connection with the port but it will not connect. I read elsewhere that I need to open a new terminal window and run some command that will finally accept the connection. I'm using docker and docker-compose to spin up a MongoDB Container. Anybody know where I go from here to ensure that I complete a connection with port 27017?? Thanks so much!

[My Current Terminal Window Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbFcV.png)

```py
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongo_user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mongo_secret
```

^ docker-compose.yml

Comment: if you type `docker ps` in the terminal, does it show you the port?

Comment: @Aaron_ab yes it does

Comment: show your docker compose.

Comment: @michalk my bad, just fixed it